# Update observed model in custom knockoutjs binding

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to integrate jQuery autocomplete extension in foreach knockout loop. I've created custom binding and autocomplete works. But after autocomplete I also need to update observable item model and cannot figure out how to do it. Here you are my code:

```
<!-- ko foreach: items -->
<input data-bind="autoComplete: { source: '/products/item-search-ajax', options: { delay: 100, max: 20, minChars: 2, extraParams: { itcode: 1 }}, findCallback: $parent.findValueCallback }, value: PartNumber" type="text">
<!-- /ko -->

<script type="text/javascript">

        ko.bindingHandlers.autoComplete = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                var settings = valueAccessor();
                var source = settings.source;
                var options = settings.options;
                var findCallback = settings.findCallback;
                $(element).autocomplete(source, options);
                $(element).result(findCallback);
                ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);
            },
            update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
                var value = valueAccessor();
                ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element,valueAccessor);
            } 
        };

        function QuoteViewModel() {
            var self = this;

            self.items = ko.observableArray(...);

            self.findValueCallback = function(event, data, formatted) {

                // Need to update Item model here from autocomplete
            };
        }

 </script>
```

Comment: jQuery UI Autocomplete? This has been done. Use the existing binding handler. http://gvas.github.io/knockout-jqueryui/autocomplete.html

Comment: It's a different jqeury autocomplete. And I could already connect autocomplete extension. I just do not know how to update observable model from custom binding.

Comment: Okay, which autocomplete library is it?

Comment: Because the initialization parameters and result handling it look *exactly* like jQuery UI Autocomplete. In which case: Use the existing bindings.

Comment: The question is not about autocomplete but how I can update observable model inside custom binding.

Comment: There is a custom binding for jQuery UI autocomplete that is tested and works very well. Use. That. It's a complete waste of time to write another one. Don't succumb to the Not-Invented-Here syndrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically pass the `$data` (which in this `foreach` would be an Item model) object into a function that returns a handler function as such:

```
self.findValueCallback = function(item) {
    return function(event, data, formatted) {
        //u have access to particular item
    }
}
```

and inside a binding: `findCallback: $parent.findValueCallback($data)`